# cursor gets hidden and cannot type after window.find()

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

this is my input field:

```
  <input type="text" id="searchField" [(ngModel)]='search' 
  (ngModelChange)='searchCalled()' class="input-text" placeholder="Filter by 
  Name">
```

and my function is:

```
  searchCalled():any {
   var text = this.search;
   (<any>window).find(text);
  }
```

after an alphabet is matched in window.find(), the cursor gets automatically hidden from the input field and I cannot type in the input field. I have to click it again in order to type. But if anything is not matched, the cursor remains there and the input field is still in focus. I have written separate functions on blur, and mouseleave to check whether it is getting blurred but it's not getting blurred which I have tested.

I tried using

```
  document.getElementById('searchField').focus()
```

but it's not working.

I am using typescript in angular 4.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you should not access the `window` object directly the way you do. Neither the `document` object so far you are using angular. Get familiar with angulars `@ViewChild` - https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild

Comment: How to implement window.find() using @ViewChild?